# SoftKeyboard Android

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

Im working in an app to modify the sounds when I key is press in the android soft-keyboard. I have download the sample soft-keyboard from Google. Now Im trying to figure out how to add sound to each or all the keys.

My question is: is it possible to assign a short customize sound to each key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    Can i change this in the already implemented keyboard?
```

You can't... it's already built and some manufactures provide their own keyboard implementations.

```
    Or should i make my own keyboard?
```

Yes, you must.

```
    If the latter is the case, how do i do that? Can i find the source code somewhere?
```

There are some open source projects of Keyboard implementations... for instance:

```
https://github.com/g1011999/Gingerbread-Keyboard/
http://code.google.com/p/softkeyboard/
```

There you can learn how to write your own keyboard, which is completely different from writing a conventional app.

My suggestion is to create a new fork of the Gingerbread-Keyboard (this supports Android 2.2 or higher only)... and then implement that specific change you want. For one of my apps I did so, and it's far easier than implementing the keyboard from scratch.

Comment: Thank you kumar great help. I did download the softkeyboard into eclipse. By any chance do you how to add sound to the softkeyboard? Is your softkeyboard app in the appstore?